# Error - There is no source code available for the current location

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, berkeley-db

When I'm trying to debug a C program written on Linux machine (right now, I'm using Visual C++ Express), I first get a *stack overflow* error. So when I clicked continue, I got another error message,

> Access violation reading location 0x00030000

So I decide to debug step by step. So when I try it, it shows me the error

> There is no source code available for the current location.

What is the reason for this error?

**The Code**

```
    #if 1
    while(1)
    #endif
    {
        fillList();
        #if 1
        {
            op_ds_bulk(ops, &total, 1);
            temp = res("Bulk Write:", total, fp);
            index = 0;
        }
        #endif

        void op_ds_bulk(u_int ops, u_int * totalp, int update)
        {
            char encode_db[] = "encode";
            if(update)
            {
                database_insert_bluk(list, ops);
                database_sync();
                *totalp = ops;
            }
            else
            {
                CHUNK prefetch[4096];
                int random = rand() % (h-ops+1);
                __os_clock(NULL, &start_time.secs, &start_time.usecs);
                database_select_end(65546, random, prefetch, ops);
                __os_clock(NULL, &end_time.secs, &end_time.usecs);
               *totalp = ops;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you took the source and recompiled it, and didn't use a cross complier or anything like that.

Comment: it's over 700 line coding . : / cant' put those coz the forum only allow over 500 chars

Comment: @mahesh, i'll try . i don't know which one to post coz i'm new to c. #if 1
 while(1)
#endif
 {
  fillList();
#if 1
  {
   op_ds_bulk(ops, &total, 1);
   temp = res("Bulk Write:", total, fp);
   index = 0;
  }
#endif

Comment: void op_ds_bulk(u_int ops, u_int * totalp, int update)
{
        char encode_db[] = "encode";
        if(update)
        {
                database_insert_bluk(list, ops);
                database_sync();
                *totalp = ops;
        }
        else
        {
                CHUNK prefetch[4096];   
                int random = rand() % (h-ops+1);
                __os_clock(NULL, &start_time.secs, &start_time.usecs);
                database_select_end(65546, random, prefetch, ops);
                __os_clock(NULL, &end_time.secs, &end_time.usecs);
                *totalp = ops;  }
}

Comment: ouch !!! i don't know how to make it easier for you to see my coding !! sorry !!!

Comment: @kevin - You can actually modify the question content and post the code there.

Comment: Thank you . I don't know that !!

Answer (score 1):

The invalid access might occur somewhere in the standard library code. The source for that is not available in the Express edition.

You might check the call stack for the part of your code that calls a library function, and work it from there.

Comment: Sorry how to check call stack and debug , I'm new to C.

Comment: A bit late, but anyway: If you run your program in debug mode, and get the "no source found" message, there should be a call stack window in the debugger, listing all active functions. Just scroll that until you find a function you recognize. That should be the place in you source where you called the part without source.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had a similar problem, maybe it is related to yours?

I had an array on the stack (you have one too - `prefetch`) and I accidently cleared it too far (out of bounds of the array), removing whatever information was beyond the array.

When you call a function, the return address is also stored on the stack (computer must know where to return from a function). Since I have cleared that, the program jumped under address 0x0 and SegFault-ed. When debugging, I also got a message "there is no source code at current location", because "current location" was 0x0 and of course there was no code there.

So I suspect that you go out-of-bounds on some array which is on the stack.

By looking at your code, I see two suspicious things:

- The size of your prefetch array is 4096, but you call `database_select_end` with parameter 65546. Maybe it is ok (no idea what that function does) but maybe it is not ;)
- 65546 is not a power of 2. 2^16=65536

Comment: Thanks you. In fact when i trace it, it show me the error as soon as it entered the second line above !!! It doesn't even get a chance to get the **database_select_end**  statement. The error shows up when it entered **void op_ds_bulk(u_int ops, u_int * totalp, int update) 
{ **.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing the same code with a different function name. It's so weird for me because it solved my problem. I don't know why.